# How to add all the column values of grouped rows in data grid row header

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

What i am trying to achieve in this WPF Application is to sum up all the value of column "size" grouped by family on Header. Is there any method in data grid that will do the sum of columns of all the rows grouped under specific category?

[image: Output]

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="False" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Name="TotalSize" Text="Total size here"  Margin="290 0 0 0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="20 0 0 0" />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window        
{      
    ObservableCollection<DownloadManager> dManager = new ObservableCollection<DownloadManager>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("dm.xml");
        XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/root/repository/MEDIA");

        foreach (XmlNode media in xnList)
        {
            string PRODUCT = media["PRODUCT"].InnerText;
            string SIZE = media["SIZE"].InnerText;
            string MEDIASTATUS = media["MEDIASTATUS"].InnerText;
            string FAMILY = media["FAMILY"].InnerText;
            dManager.Add(new DownloadManager { Name = PRODUCT, Size = SIZE, Description = MEDIASTATUS, Family = FAMILY });
        }

        ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(dManager);
        collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Family"));
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;             
    }
}

public class DownloadManager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
}
```

**XML**

```
<root>
  <repository >
    <MEDIA>
      <PRODUCT>MS Office</PRODUCT>
      <FAMILY>Paid</FAMILY>
      <SIZE>1056</SIZE>
      <MEDIASTATUS>LIVE</MEDIASTATUS>
    </MEDIA>

    <MEDIA>
      <PRODUCT>Matlab</PRODUCT>
      <FAMILY>Paid</FAMILY>
      <SIZE>2096</SIZE>
      <MEDIASTATUS>LIVE</MEDIASTATUS>
    </MEDIA>

    <MEDIA>
      <PRODUCT>Winzip</PRODUCT>
      <FAMILY>Free</FAMILY>
      <SIZE>119</SIZE>
      <MEDIASTATUS>LIVE</MEDIASTATUS>
    </MEDIA>

    <MEDIA>
      <PRODUCT>Team Viewer</PRODUCT>
      <FAMILY>Free</FAMILY>
      <SIZE>256</SIZE>
      <MEDIASTATUS>LIVE</MEDIASTATUS>
    </MEDIA>

    <MEDIA>
      <PRODUCT>Coral Draw</PRODUCT>
      <FAMILY>Paid</FAMILY>
      <SIZE>3110</SIZE>
      <MEDIASTATUS>LIVE</MEDIASTATUS>
    </MEDIA>

    <MEDIA>
      <PRODUCT>Photoshop</PRODUCT>
      <FAMILY>Free</FAMILY>
      <SIZE>2056</SIZE>
      <MEDIASTATUS>LIVE</MEDIASTATUS>
    </MEDIA>

  </repository>
</root>
```

Comment: Instead of "Total size here" use `{Binding ItemCount}`. :-)

Comment: @XAMlMAX :Item count, counts the row. i need the summation of column "Size"

Comment: Column size is the same for every group, what you need is the length of strings inside of a particular column. You need to update your Question as it is misleading.

Comment: @XAMlMAX How is "*sum up all the value of column 'size'* " unclear? I.E. `Paid Total size = 1056 + 2096 + 3110` and `Free Total size = 119 + 256 + 2056`

Comment: @OhBeWise That's because I misread the question. As you can see in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution I can think of is to create a `Converter` class - implementing the `Convert` method to cycle through the grouped items, summing the `Size` values, and formatting the return string as desired:

```
public class SumGroupConverter : IValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
          GroupItem groupItem = value as GroupItem;
          CollectionViewGroup collectionViewGroup = groupItem.Content as CollectionViewGroup;
          int sum = 0;

          foreach (var item in collectionViewGroup.Items)
          {
              DownloadManager dman = item as DownloadManager;
              int size = 0;
              int.TryParse(dman.Size, out size);
              sum += size;
          }

          return string.Format("Total size: {0}", sum);
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }
```

Then, assuming in your xaml you have a line such as `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"`, then you can add the following to your `Window.Resources`:

```
<local:SumGroupConverter x:Key="SumTitle"/>
```

And for your `TextBox` within the `Expander`:

```
<TextBlock 
    Name="TotalSize" 
    Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupItem}}, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=SumTitle}}"  
    Margin="290 0 0 0"/>
```

Results:

[image: total size screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. it worked like a charm. Accepted your answer will thumb up after 5 hrs.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the complete code example - made it a lot easier.